# ArrayList has two elements, is it possible to find an average of the int element?

Tags: java, arraylist, average

This small project consists of two classes and one ArrayList. The ArrayList has two elements: a `name` and a `score`. Is it possible to find the average of the element `score`?

Class `classroom`:

```
/**
 * This class creates the names and scores of the students
 */
public class Classroom
{
public int score;
public String name;

/**
 * Constructor for the Class that adds a name and a score.
 */
public Classroom(String aName, int aScore)
{
    score = aScore;
    name = aName;
}

/**
 * Return the name of the students
 */
public String returnName()
{
    return name;
}

/**
 * Return the scores
 */
public int returnScore()
{
    return score;
}
}
```

Class `TestScores`:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Print test scrose and student names as well as he average for the class.
 */
public class TestScores
{
private ArrayList<Classroom> scores;
public int studentScores;

/**
 * Create a new ArrayList of scores and add some scores
 */
public TestScores()
{
    scores = new ArrayList<Classroom>();
}

/**
 * Add a new student and a new score.
 */
public void add (String name, int score)
{
    scores.add(new Classroom(name, score));
        if(score > 100){
            System.out.println("The score cannot be more than 100");
        }

}
```

Wouldn't you be able to use a for each loop, create a local variable to store the student score from the `returnScore` method in the classroom class and divide it by the array size?

Comment: you can iterate through ArrayList and find all scores, sum them up to calculate the average.

Comment: ...or use Java 8 streams, which makes the whole thing much more concise.

Comment: I suggest you three ways, look at my answer

Comment: Consider naming your getters getXxx as well, rather than returnXxx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you `returnScore()` for every element in your `scores` in a loop, and add each `returnScore()` to a local variable, and then divide that variable by `scores.Size()`, you should get what you are looking for. Please let me know if I misunderstood the question. Do this in your TestScores class.

Comment: So this should do it but it does not print the average but a score of each person. What am I doing wrong here?     public void average()
    {
        for(Classroom average : scores){
            System.out.println("The class average score is " + (average.returnScore()/scores.size()));
        }
        }

Comment: Wait I completely messed up. Let me fix it

Answer (score 4):

Using Java 8 streams, this should do the work

```
public double getAvg(){
    return scores.stream()
                 .mapToInt(x -> x.returnScore())
                 .average()
                 .getAsDouble();
}
```

Comment: I suggest `ClassRoom::returnScore` instead of `x -> x.returnScore()`, but that may be personal preference. And of course Streams are an advanced topic, so I suggest sticking with the "manual" way first, until one is fluent enough in Java.

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz Yes I thought of first doing it using the method reference but then changed my mind to make sure OP's understanding what is happening.

Comment: Totally legit, but of course, since the original question was along the lines of "could I use a loop to...", I think that the OP still has some way to go before understanding that in any case ;-)

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I haven't learned streams yet but it works when I put it in!

Comment: @feelingstoned Another way would've been to loop etc. But its too much code for little result :) This way is way better. And that's how we learn. Feel free to accept the answer of course.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution is to run a for loop on array list and calculate the sum of score and divide by the array size.

But do this in your TestScores class or some other class. The ClassRoom is individual score so you can't store the total or average in that class.

Secondly your modelling is not correct. You calling it ClassRoom whereas it can have only one Student and its score.

Also in your add method your check of score > 100 is after you added the score. You should check before and only add to list if it is not greater than 100.

Comment: But of course, with Java 8, we have Streams now, which would be more elegant.

Comment: Certainly with Java 8 we have elegant solution

Comment: Yeah I wrote a method in the testscores. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be add two static variable in the class Classroom:
*totalScore* and *totalStudents*. Then in the constructor of Classroom you increment this two variables (totalScore++,totalStudents++).
Finally you can create a Static Method in the class Classroom to get the average:

```
public static double getAverage(){
    return (double)totalScore/(double)totalStudents;
}
```